# Seaborn catplot + barplot : extra axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I use Seaborn/Matplotlib to display different outputs (time and distance for example) for different parameters. I would like to associate the two outputs on the same plot, thus I use seaborn's satplot and barplot.

My problem is I don't get the expected display. The graph is here but some noisy extra axis appear.

I'm running the following code

```
ax = plt.subplot(311)
ax2 = ax.twinx()

data = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.barplot(ax=ax, x="day",y="total_bill", hue="size" , data=data, ci=None)
ax.set_yscale("log")

sns.catplot(data=data, x="day", y="tip", ax=ax2, hue="size", kind="swarm", palette="bright")
```

And I have the following result :

[image]

Could you help me to remove this extra axis ? It is especially inconvenient when having multiple subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra axes you see is the `catplot` you create. `catplot` is a figure-level function (i.e. it creates its own figure); and hence does not really have an `ax` argument. One could see it as bug that it still allows for it. What you would probably like to do is to create a `sns.swarmplot` instead, which does have the `ax` argument.

Answer (score 2):

The extra axis you see is the one returned by the `catplot`. To get rid of it, you can add the following line after the `sns.catplot(...)` where the index `2` refers to the count of the figure.

```
plt.close(2)
```

To test that, if you use `plt.close(1)`, it will remove the main figure containing bar chart

Comment: Do you have an idea why caplot generates another axis while I specified `ax=ax2`? It creates another figure ?

Comment: @matthiasbe : The same reason what IOBE pointed out in his answer above

Comment: Although I like your solution, I accepted IOBE's answers as it is more convenient in my usecase.

Comment: @matthiasbe : No issues at all. We are all one community :)